# JSF 2: How show different ajax status in same input?

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I would like to validate every field in my form when each field  lose the focus, when this happens i would like these actions happen:

1) in the right side of the field appears an image, a .gif (to represent that the system is checking the user input)

2) when finished  appears another .gif (which depends of the input, 'sucess.gif' or 'error.gif', for example) and a message on the right side.

I don't want to use popup or something like, the user is gonna lose  usability  and i don't want this.

I'm trying to do something like this, this is what i have done so far:

```
<h:form id="form">
    <h:panelGrid columns="3" >
        <h:outputLabel for="first_name" value="First Name:" />
        <h:inputText id="first_name" value="#{register.bean.firstName}" >
            <f:ajax event="blur" render="m_first_name" />
        </h:inputText>

        <a4j:status name="ajaxStatus">
            <f:facet name="start">
                <h:graphicImage name="loader.gif" library="images" />
                <h:outputText value="Processing ..." />
            </f:facet>
        </a4j:status>

        <a4j:commandButton value="Register !" action="#{register.validateName}" status="ajaxStatus" />

    </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

I was searching for some solution on Google and I think

```
<a:a4j ... >
```

is my best option, because of the `onbegin` and `oncomplete` attributes.
There's some attribute as these in some native tag in JSF 2 ?

**UPDATE**:
@BalusC approach:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
    <h:head>
        <title>Insert title here</title>

        <script type="text/javascript">

        function showProgress(data) {
            var inputElement = data.source; // The HTML DOM input element.
            var ajaxStatus = data.status; // Can be "begin", "success" and "complete"
            var messageForInputElement = document.getElementById(inputElement.id + "_message");

            switch (ajaxStatus) {
                case "begin": // This is called right before ajax request is been sent.
                    messageForInputElement.innerHTML = "validating...";
                    break;

                case "complete": // This is called right after ajax response is received.
                    messageForInputElement.innerHTML = "";
                    break;

                case "success": // This is called when ajax response is successfully processed.
                    if (messageForInputElement.innerHTML.length == 0) { // So, no message has been set.
                        messageForInputElement.innerHTML = "valid!";
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
        </script>

    </h:head>

    <h:body>
        <h:form id="form">
            <h:panelGrid columns="3">
                <h:outputLabel for="first_name" value="First Name" />
                <h:inputText id="first_name" value="#{bean.firstName}" required="true">
                    <f:ajax event="blur" render="first_name_message" onevent="showProgress" />
                </h:inputText>
                <h:message id="first_name_message" for="first_name" />

                <h:panelGroup />
                <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{register.doSomething}">
                    <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form" />
                </h:commandButton>
                <h:messages globalOnly="true" layout="table" />
            </h:panelGrid>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

And this is my bean:

```
@ManageBean
@ViewScope
..

public void doSomething(){
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Ajax4jsf's `onbegin` and `oncomplete` attributes are just extra abstractions of the existing `onevent` attribute of the JSF2 standard [`<f:ajax>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/ajax.html) tag. You only need to bring in some extra JavaScript code in to achieve the same functionality.

Here's a kickoff example:

```xml
<h:form>
    <h:panelGrid columns="3">
        <h:outputLabel for="input1" value="Input 1" />
        <h:inputText id="input1" value="#{bean.input1}" required="true">
            <f:ajax event="blur" render="input1_message" onevent="showProgress" />
        </h:inputText>
        <h:message id="input1_message" for="input1" />

        <h:outputLabel for="input2" value="Input 2" />
        <h:inputText id="input2" value="#{bean.input2}" required="true">
            <f:ajax event="blur" render="input2_message" onevent="showProgress" />
        </h:inputText>
        <h:message id="input2_message" for="input2" />

        <h:panelGroup />
        <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{bean.submit}">
            <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form" />
        </h:commandButton>
        <h:messages globalOnly="true" layout="table" />
    </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

Here's a basic kickoff example the `showProgress` function. The `data` argument is a JS object whose properties are already described in tables 14-4 and 14-3 of the [JSF specification](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr314/index.html).

```
function showProgress(data) {
    var inputElement = data.source; // The HTML DOM input element.
    var ajaxStatus = data.status; // Can be "begin", "success" and "complete"

    var messageForInputElement = document.getElementById(inputElement.id + "_message");

    switch (ajaxStatus) {
        case "begin": // This is called right before ajax request is been sent.
            messageForInputElement.innerHTML = "validating...";
            break;

        case "complete": // This is called right after ajax response is received.
            messageForInputElement.innerHTML = "";
            break;

        case "success": // This is called when ajax response is successfully processed.
            if (messageForInputElement.innerHTML.length == 0) { // So, no message has been set.
                messageForInputElement.innerHTML = "valid!";
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

You could substitute the `innerHTML` of this kickoff example with for example images or adding/removing CSS style class on the message element which uses CSS background images, etc. This is not exactly trivial to keep crossbrowser compatible. I'd suggest to throw in some [jQuery](http://jquery.com) in there.

Basically, the Ajax4jsf's `onbegin` and `oncomplete` attributes removes the need that you've to write a whole JS function with a `switch` to achieve the desired functionality. You could just refer directly some JavaScript functions which do the same as the lines *inside* the `case` statements of the `switch`. It's just an extra abstraction. You may want to consider using it so that amount of boilerplate code is minimized.

Comment: I tried your approach but the status that you put in JS changes too fast. It's like if not waited for method processed bean . Sorry the late to answer it's because i was trying to solve this. i update my post to show you how I'm doing.

Comment: You was asking to apply this on input validation, not on action methods. To have progress for action method as well, just add another `onevent` to the `<f:ajax>` of the command button with a slight different JS function.