# Is there any difference between f:ajax and a4j:ajax?

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, richfaces

Is there any significant difference between `f:ajax` and `a4j:ajax` tags?

I know about a4j:ajax from Richfaces 4 is based on native f:ajax JSF2 tag adding some attributes not found in f:ajax like `onbegin`, `onbeforedoupdate`, `bypassUpdates`, `limitRender`, `status` and `focus` but which one to use when I only need to send a simple ajax request or partial rendering ? Is there performance issues between f:ajax and a4j:ajax?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `<a4j:ajax>` tag is just the more convenient form of the basic `<f:ajax>` tag. You can find a nice overview of all differences in [this page](http://maxkatz.sys-con.com/node/1505643/mobile).

The `execute` attribute supports an extra `@region` value pointing to the `<a4j:region>`. Any EL in `execute` and `render` attributes is resolved in current request instead of in initial request.

The JS function of the `onevent` attribute of both tags will be invoked 3 times (the passed-in `data.status` has then the values `begin`, `complete`, `success`). This forces you to use a `switch` or `if` when you're only interested in one of them or want to treat them differently. The `<a4j:ajax>` makes this more convenient with `onbegin`, `onbeforedomupdate` and `oncomplete` attributes respectively. See also this related question: [JSF 2: How show different ajax status in same input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7043840/jsf-2-how-show-different-ajax-status-in-same-input)

If you're not interested in any of those enhancements, then using `<f:ajax>` should be perfectly fine as well. The performance difference is (and must be) totally negligible and not be the reason to choose one over the other.

Answer (score 2):

Here is more information on the differences between f:ajax and a4j:ajax: http://mkblog.exadel.com/2010/08/what-richfaces-a4jajax-adds-on-top-jsf-2-fajax-tag/

Comment: Thanks Max, your blog is nice

Comment: Hallo Max. The link doesn't seem to work anymore. Can I find the information anywhrere else?

Comment: Hi - here is the correct link: https://maxkatz.org/2010/08/19/what-richfaces-a4jajax-adds-on-top-jsf-2-fajax-tag/ (I migrated my blog to my own domain many yeas ago).