# How to ajax enable h:selectManyCheckbox in Richfaces 4.0 with an ActionEvent method binding

Tags: ajax, jsf, richfaces

I am using Richfaces 4.0, checking to ajax enable h:selectManyCheckbox. I don't see the availablity of a4j:support tag. In earlier versions is was there, but it looks like is not available anymore. What is the alternative?

Answer (score 0):

check this issue, you will find out the solution to render Ajax [issues_jboss_RF_8744](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RF-8744)

Answer (score 0):

The old RichFaces 3.x `<a4j:support>` is replaced by the new RichFaces 4.x `<a4j:ajax>`. The standard JSF 2.x `<f:ajax>` should however work as good.

#### See also:

- [RichFaces 3.3 to 4.0 Migration Guide](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/RichFacesMigrationGuide33x-4xMigration) - [a4j components](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/RichFacesMigrationGuide33x-4xMigration-ComponentsMigration-A4jComponents)
- [Is there any difference between f:ajax and a4j:ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7590361/is-there-any-difference-between-fajax-and-a4jajax/7590780#7590780)