# Passing extra parameter to f:ajax onevent function

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsf-2

In my **JSF 2.0** (on **JBoss AS 7**) project, I would like on my ajax submitted forms to display a little icon status triggered on begin and complete phases, to let the end user know that something is still happening.

The [primefaces `p:ajaxStatus`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/pprAjaxStatus.jsf) is not useful here, as I'd like to have many different icons at different places in my page.

I found a bit of the solution in this question: "[How show different ajax status in same input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7043840/jsf-2-how-show-different-ajax-status-in-same-input)", but I still have a problem: in order to make my javascript function reusable, I need to provide an extra parameter to the call.

I did something like this:

```
<h:commandLink value="do something boy!">
    <f:ajax render="@form" execute="@form" listener="#{myBean.doStuff}"
        onevent="showProgress" />
    <f:param name="extraParam" value="extraValue" />
</h:commandLink>
```

and I can see the parameter "extraParam" sent to the server through the request, but in my javascript `showProgress` method I cannot recover it through the only given parameter.

So my questions is: **can I provide to my `f:ajax onevent` javascript method an additionnal parameter through `f:param` (or maybe `f:attribute`, or anything else)?**

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Wrap it in an anonymous function wherein you pass it as extra argument.

```
<h:commandLink value="do something boy!">
    <f:ajax render="@form" execute="@form" listener="#{myBean.doStuff}"
        onevent="function(data) { showProgress(data, 'extraValue') }" />
</h:commandLink>
```

with

```
function showProgress(data, extraParam) {
    // Use "data" argument the usual way.
    // The "extraParam" argument will contain "extraValue" in above example.
}
```

Comment: Can this 'extraValue' be a jsf expression? I mean can be something like `onevent="function(data) { showProgress(data, '#{myBean.whatever}') }` ? Thx!

Comment: Auto-response: Yes, it can be used,  :)