# JSF2 cant pass a value to a new pop window

Tags: java, jsf

I got some troubles with some codes. Now I try to modify/delete personal information , but I enter an invalid value try modify/delete , it's still pop a new window . I dont know how to modify those code for i enter an invalid value , it will not pop a window . 
I have other question . When I enter a valid value , the value cant pass to pop window , like I enter a name to go grab id value , the value cant pass to pop window , how can I reslove it . Thank all !

HTML

```
<h:panelGrid columns="3" cellspacing="20">
     <h:outputLabel for="name" value="Modify Name"/> <p:inputText value="#{modify.enName}"/>
     <h:commandButton value="Modify System"  style="height:35px" onclick="window.open('#{modify.domodify()}','modify',
                                                      'width=500,height=400,status=yes,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes') ; return false;"/>
</h:panelGrid>
```

Java Code

```
 public String domodify() {
    try {
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("com.mycompany_SuneCoolingSystem_war_1.0-SNAPSHOTPU");
        EmployeeJpaController jpaController = new EmployeeJpaController(null, emf);
        EntityManager e = jpaController.getEntityManager();
        Query q = e.createNamedQuery("Employee.findByEnName");
        q.setParameter("enName", getEnName());
        System.out.println(getEnName());
        List resultList = q.getResultList();
        Employee result = (Employee) resultList.get(0);

        id = result.getId();
        name = result.getName();
        idNumber = result.getIdNumber();
        constellation = result.getConstellation();
        email = result.getEmail();
        enName = result.getEnName();

        rego="CRUD/Modify.xhtml";
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN, "No Man", ""));
        rego = "index.xhtml";
    }
    return rego;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
onclick="window.open('#{modify.domodify()}','modify', 'width=500,height=400,status=yes,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes')
```

This code means *when clicked, open a new window and perform the action to check what URL is returned.* The windows is opened before any logic is executed.

You should perform an ajax call to the modify with `f:ajax` (or your component library equivalent, if you want) and use `onevent` to launch the correct javascript when the ajax calls ends in success and returning the expected value.

See [JSF 2: How show different ajax status in same input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7043840/jsf-2-how-show-different-ajax-status-in-same-input) to see an example of dealing with `onevent`.