# Upgrading from JSF 1.x to JSF 2.3 replacing ajax4JSF commands with new JSF for below line of code and similar

Tags: jsf-2, jsf-1.2, tomahawk

Upgrading legacy JSF 1.x to JSF 2.3.6 trying to figure out best course action.
This is my old line of code that I would like to now how to change it correctly in JSF 2.3

```
<a4j:status for="assignInventoryRegion" stopText="" startText="Request under process" startStyle="color:green"/>
```

Comment: In plain jsf there is no 1:1 counterpart. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7043840/jsf-2-how-show-different-ajax-status-in-same-input complementary component suits like PrimeFaces etc.. do have these.

Comment: Question would it be better for me to introduce PrimeFaces to replace the A4J or do the java script work arounds?   I have several a4j:status references in my html?

Comment: A4j is deprecated, as is tomahawk... you can do it in plain jsf but PrimeFaces or comparable Frameworks are a good way. Opinionated remark from me though